# Kendo DateTimePicker is not sending the selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When i submit my form kendo datetimepicker is not sending the selected value, it sends
0001-01-01 even when i manually input a date to the database and then edit it from my application ,it will show 0001-01-1 again.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("News_Events", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "News_Events" }))
                {  


      <p>
            <label class="label-ant">Date To</label>
            @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
              .Name("end")
              .Value(Model.NewsEventsDateTo)
              .Min(DateTime.Today)
              .ParseFormats(new string[] { "MM/dd/yyyy" })
              .Events(e => e.Change("endChange"))
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px;" })
              )

        </p>
```

Comment: You have not shown you model or the controller method, but it appears you have a property named `NewsEventsDateTo`, so why are you giving the controls a `name="end"` which will not bind back to your model? Use `.DatePickerFor(m => m.NewsEventsDateTo)....`

Comment: @StephenMuecke .DatePickerFor(m => m.NewsEventsDateTo) gives an error but changing the id name worked , thanks

Comment: What error? It works fine.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  it says unknown method 'DateTimePicker(?)' of 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory'. i tried Datepicker too

Comment: Oops, sorry, it was meant to be `Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(m => m.NewsEventsDateTo)`

Comment: cool , it works , thx again @StephenMuecke